# Is it possible to install Remote Server Administrative Tools on a Windows Server 2012?

Tags: remote-server, windows-server-2012

I understand that RSAT is used to manage domain controllers remotely from a computer that is not a domain controller,I found links to download RSAT for Windows 8, 7 or Vista, but nothing to download it on a windows server. I need to use it on a windows server 2012, is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows Server 2012 (and 2008 as well) the Remote Server Administration Tools are available for installation using the Add Roles and Features wizard, so you don't need to download it like you would on a client OS, eg you can install the tools from there without installing the associated roles.

You'll find it under Features and you can then install all of them or just those tools you need. You'll also find Group Policy Management listed separately under the features list, though I'm not sure why it's not listed under the RSAT items.

Comment: Thank you, I tried using Add roles and Features and it worked.